# Excel through OleDb shows numbers differently...depending on whether spreadsheet is open?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, ado.net, oledb

I'm opening an Excel worksheet into a DataTable using OleDb like this:

```
string select = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}$]", worksheetName);
using (var con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
using (var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(select, con))
{
    con.Open();
    var dt = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();
    return dt;
}
```

Then I loop through the rows of the DataTable reading various bits of data like this:

```
decimal charge;
bool isChargeReadable = 
    decimal.TryParse(row["Charge"].ToString(), out charge);
```

I discovered just now that my code was choking on cells with dollar amounts such as "$1100.00", which it can't parse to decimal.  Not so surprising...except that this is code that was working perfectly before just now.

Further investigation revealed that if I run this code **while the workbook is open**, it sees one of those cells as "1100".  If I run it while the workbook is closed, it sees "$1100.00".

Why is this happening?  Obviously I'll have to rework my code to function while the workbook is closed, but why would it make a difference?  I would've thought it would just be reading the saved workbook.

The connection string I'm using is this...

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
    Data Source={0};
    Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"";"
```

...where {0} is replaced by the Excel file name, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that my oledb operations work better in excel withOUT an IMEX=number set.  Perhaps your problem is there?

Comment: Did you see the connection string I included?

Comment: OH, I meant withOUT an IMEX.  I had the devil's own time doing anything with oledb to excel until I removed the IMEX= flag.  Typo.

Comment: See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/194124/EN-US/ for more explanation about the IMEX settings.

Comment: Well...that could be it, then.  Alas, I'll never know, because I don't work at that place anymore.  Maybe this will help someone else, though.